# Two different languages

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have Ubuntu 14.04. I want to keep the system in english language but I need the system to have regional setup of italy, like keyboard, currency etc. I couldn't find a way to do this setup. How can I get it?

I've looked around to try to find an option, and I followed [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298708/how-do-i-switch-between-keyboard-layouts). But I don't have that panel on my ubuntu. My system setting is different:

[image: system settings panel]

As you can see I have no "keyboard layout" icon. there is a "text entry" icon that has the same design but does a totally different thing and I cannot change keyboard there.

Inside language support There is a keyboad langua (in the regional panel) but I cannot choose the keyboard that I want, only available keyboards for english language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep your system in English and change the regional format to your desired location:

1. First, click on the "Language Support"
   [image: System settings]
2. Install the desired language by clicking "Install / Remove Languages..."
   [image: Language support]
3. Italian, in this case
   [image: Install / Remove Language]
4. After it's done, go to "Regional Formats".
   Eccolo! The language you just installed will be available there.
   [image]