# Keyboard Language fast change

Tags: shortcuts

You know in windows to change the language of keyboard is shift + alt. is there any shortcut for this in ubuntu ? Because i cant find one and its super annoying to switch it manually! Thanks for answering !

Comment: Which version and flavor of Ubuntu are you using? Have you tried Super+Space? Super is the key that usually has Windows logo. Go to **Settings > Devices> Keyboard** scroll down to **Typing** to see what the shortcuts are set to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch between keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298708/how-do-i-switch-between-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: @AkbarkhonVariskhanov not a duplicate because here, the user asks for a quick way, i.e. using a hotkey.

Answer (score 4):

In the standard Ubuntu desktop, with Gnome Shell, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is the default keyboard  shortcut to switch between input sources (i.e., different installed keyboard layouts).

If you have more than a few layouts installed, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will be valuable to cycle in reversed order through the available input sources.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the official Ubuntu documentation for your version. You can find the answer to your question by opening the **Help** program and typing *Use alternative input sources* in the search bar.

You can also access those documents online:

- for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html
- for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic https://help.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en
- for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en