# Installing Bulgarian keyboard language

Tags: keyboard, settings, language-support, system-settings

I'm new to Linux. I'm from Bulgaria and need Bulgarian language.

I searched in settings and find nothing. I find files in  https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/language-pack-bg,  but how to install it on Kubuntu 21.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch between keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298708/how-do-i-switch-between-keyboard-layouts)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [Van Wilder's](https://askubuntu.com/a/1369182/1109461) answer, it should be mentioned that the Bulgarian keyboard layout is a bit special. To be able to access 3rd and 4th level symbols you need to define a third level key.

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package if it's not installed already.
- Open *Tweaks* and navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse* -> *Additional Layout Options* -> *Key to choose the 3rd level*.
- Check the *Right Alt* option.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the Activities overview and start typing Settings.
2. Click on Settings.
3. Click Region & Language in the sidebar to open the panel.
4. Click the + button in the Input Sources section, select the language which is associated with the layout, then select a layout and press Add.

Follow the documentation for more information. [Click here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en)