# Keyboard language

Tags: keyboard, language-support

I have a problem with Ubuntu version 20.04.5, only accept english language in keyboard. I need to change it for portuguese language.
When I installed Ubuntu, all languages were removed automatically. Now I can`t in settings setup to portuguese language.

Thanks

Comment: Try doing the steps provided in the [ubuntu docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/20.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html.en) and see if they work for you.

Comment: Keyboard layouts, system and additional language packages are very different things. Which one you have a problem with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I switch between keyboard layouts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298708/how-do-i-switch-between-keyboard-layouts)

Comment: All languages were removed? Can you please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu docs, I found the answer for my question in settings, region and language. Now my keyboard is working perfect.